# base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm having trouble overloading my `<<` output operator. The error doesn't seem to be the overload itself, but the implementation within it because the same error occurs for the `value()` function.

The error (cygwin):

> DeckOfCards.cpp: In function `std::ostream&
>   deck::operator<<(std::ostream&, const deck::LinkedList&)`:
>   DeckOfCards.cpp:81:20: error: base operand of `->` has non-pointer
>   type `const deck::LinkedList`
>
> ```
>     return os << list->value();
> ```
>
> ---
>
> DeckOfCards.cpp: In member function `void
>   deck::DeckOfCards::value(deck::LinkedList&)`:
>   DeckOfCards.cpp:100:15: error: base operand of `->` has non-pointer
>   type `deck::LinkedList`
>
> ```
>     cout << list->getListData();
> ```

Here's the relevant code:

#### DeckOfCards.cpp

```
// overloaded cout operator                              
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const LinkedList& list) {
    return os << list->value();
}


// returns all cards as a string
void DeckOfCards::value(LinkedList& list) {
    cout << list->getListData();
}
```

#### LinkedList.cpp

```
Node::value_type LinkedList::getListData() {
    for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->getNext()) {
        contents += current->getData() + " ";
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Why do I get those errors?

Comment: Because `LinkedList` is not a pointer? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's telling you `list` is not a pointer; it's a reference or something else.

Comment: You probably mean `list.value()`.

Comment: LinkedList is certainly not a pointer, and likely doesn't have operator -> defined on  it.

Comment: Don't try to learn C++ by trial and error. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is neither an interactive tutorial nor a helpdesk.

Answer (score 1):

`->` operator cannot be used if its lefthand operand is neither a pointer nor a class with overloaded `->` operator. Try using `.` operator like `list.value()` and `list.getListData()` instead.

Comment: This is a very low-quality question, rewarding  it with answers is not a thing to do.

Comment: This does not match the declaration of the function `value` and will thus not compile.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I'm getting a new error now though:   
`DeckOfCards.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& deck::operator<<(std::ostream&, const deck::LinkedList&)’:
DeckOfCards.cpp:81:21: error: ‘const class deck::LinkedList’ has no member named ‘value’
   return os << list.value();
`
     It can't find `value`?

Comment: @SergeyA That's really really subjective and still very discussed on meta, who're you to say it's not a thing to do?

Comment: @SergeyA Do not dictate what to do others.

Comment: @jeffbobmate Your member function value has a parameter without a default argument. So you may not call it without an argument.